# Magento How do I set the product price to 4 decimal places

Tags: magento

For a UK or Europe store we have to show inc VAT prices. i.e. a product selling for £15.95 on the store front would be stored in the admin as £13.5744 - so that when the VAT(17.5%) is added it will make £15.95

Unfortunately Mag seems to only store the price to 2dp. Even is you enter 13.5744 in the admin for the price - you get 13.57 on refresh.

Is it possible to store admin product price in 4dp and at frontend we show on 2dp?.

Cheers,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my understanding, you would need to take a close look at lib/Zend/Currency.php

Further investigating you would need to adjust the precision to 4 instead of 2:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.currency.options.html
(**edit:** updated link to latest available version)

This thread has more details on implementing such as well, it looks as though Magento also does some price formatting else where also:

[http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16337/](https://web.archive.org/web/20131130025754/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16337/)

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php

```
return number_format($value, 4, null, '');
```

I know its not a definitive answer but hopefully leads you in the right direction.

Comment: return number_format($value, 4, null, '');
It works for me.thanks

Comment: make sure your not modifying app/code/core/ but make a copy of the dir/file to app/code/local/ instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the function roundPrice() that might have been updated as well. This can be found in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

Incase you are still stuck.

Comment: answer worked very well and I have checked all price fields in quote and order table

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to change Magento code is available free extension [CurrencyManager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/niro/extension/5823/et_currencymanager) that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 places to replace/overwrite:

- app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php (\Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::format)
- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php (\Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice)
- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php (\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price::getEscapedValue)

and in admin...

- app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php (\Mage_Sales_Model_Order::formatPrice and \Mage_Sales_Model_Order::formatBasePrice)
- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Renderer/Default.php (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Renderer_Default (which extends Abstract.. you must implement displayPrice method))

Also, you can check the module I created to rewrite these classes on github.

https://github.com/r-martins/Magento-PriceDecimals/